# python coverage missing tests

Tags: python, nose, coverage.py

I'm running python coverage but my coverage is not 100%.

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

test_utils.py

```
from python_coverage import utils
import unittest


class TestAdd(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Test the add function from the mymath library
    """

    def test_add_integers(self):
        """
        Test that the addition of two integers returns the correct total
        """
        result = utils.add(1, 2)
        self.assertEqual(result, 3)

    def test_add_floats(self):
        """
        Test that the addition of two floats returns the correct result
        """
        result = utils.add(10.5, 2)
        self.assertEqual(result, 12.5)

    def test_add_strings(self):
        """
        Test the addition of two strings returns the two string as one
        concatenated string
        """
        result = utils.add('abc', 'def')
        self.assertEqual(result, 'abcdef')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

coverage report -m

```
Name                          Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------
python_coverage/__init__.py       0      0   100%
python_coverage/utils.py          2      1    50%   2
tests/test_utils.py              12      6    50%   7-8, 11-12, 15-16
-----------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                            14      7    50%
```

I copied the code from that link and run the report and here is it -

```
Name                          Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------
python_coverage/__init__.py       0      0   100%
python_coverage/utils.py          2      1    50%   2
tests/test_utils.py              14      8    43%   14-15, 21-22, 29-33
-----------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                            16      9    44%
```

Comment: It looks like you are running coverage on your tests. That does not make any sense. Just run the coverage on the source code.

Comment: Im trying to follow this blog - https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/07/20/an-intro-to-coverage-py/ and here its run against the test file - coverage run test_mymath.py

Comment: The test is referencing lines of code that is not in the original code you posted here. There are no line 22-22 etc. Please post your WHOLE source code.

Comment: Updated the correct code..when I run - nosetests --with-coverage - its 100% passed.

Comment: I have no idea why this happens. The only thing I can think of is to do `from python_coverage.utils import add`, and change the method calls.

Comment: Its just weird, after running the nosetests --with-coverage and then re-running coverage now, everything looks good, looks like something got corrupt, not sure, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not testing the output of methods. This test:

```
r = utils.add(2,3)
self.assertEqual(5,5)
```

does not actually test the value of `r`. Try changing this to:

```
r = utils.add(2, 3)
self.assertEqual(r, 5)
```

The same with `TestAdd.test_add_float`.

Comment: thanks..its a valid issues, but that doesn't work either..still my coverage is not 100%

Comment: What does it say now? Can you post the updated values?

Comment: added the report..I took the exact code from the link and rran it.